Keycloak Not Redirecting To My VUE Application & Always moving to Error Block with Error Being 'Undefined'
My Keycloak is running on port 8080 and I have setup client and realm and user, but keycloak is not getting inside the success block it goes inside the error block with error=undefinded.
Client Config:
redirectUri: http://localhost:8081/*
rootUrl: http://localhost:8080
webOrigins: *
adminUrl: http://localhost:8080/
The URL after login:  http://localhost:8081/*#iss=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Frealms%2Fvue-test
And If I use onLoad:'login-required' it continuously redirects me to a blank page and if 'check-sso' it just redirects me one time. I believe it should redirect me to keycloak login page but it is not.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueLogger from 'vuejs-logger';
import * as Keycloak from 'keycloak-js'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

const options = {
  isEnabled: true,
  logLevel: Vue.config.productionTip ? 'error' : 'debug',
  stringifyArguments: false,
  showLogLevel: true,
  showMethodName: true,
  separator: '|',
  showConsoleColors: true
};
Vue.use(VueLogger, options);


//keycloak init options
let initOptions = {
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/', realm: 'vue-test', clientId: 'vue-test-app', onLoad: 'check-sso', redirectUri:'http://localhost:8081/*'
}

let keycloak = Keycloak(initOptions);

keycloak.init({ onLoad: initOptions.onLoad, redirectUri: initOptions.redirectUri }).success((auth) => {

  if (!auth) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    console.log("Not Authenticated");
    // window.location.reload();
  } else {
    Vue.$log.info("Authenticated");
  }
  new Vue({
    render: h => h(App),
  }).$mount('#app')




  // TODO: Maybe dont store the token in the localstore, rather use it direct from the keycloak.token object
  localStorage.setItem("vue-token", keycloak.token);
  localStorage.setItem("vue-refresh-token", keycloak.refreshToken);


  //
  setInterval(() => {
    keycloak.updateToken(70).success((refreshed) => {
      if (refreshed) {
        Vue.$log.debug('Token refreshed');
      } else {
        Vue.$log.warn('Token not refreshed, valid for '
          + Math.round(keycloak.tokenParsed.exp + keycloak.timeSkew - new Date().getTime() / 1000) + ' seconds');
      }
    }).error(() => {
      Vue.$log.error('Failed to refresh token');
    });


  }, 600000)

}).error((err) => {
  Vue.$log.error("Authenticated Failed", err);
});




I tried removing the wildcard * from the redirectUri.
I want my App component to show.

do u see any error in your keycloak console?
